# Need a Javascript URL Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, soundcloud

Wondering if someone could help with out with creating a regex..

Basically, taking an iFrame's src, and seeing if it's from SoundCloud. If it is, return its id. For example:

```
var src = 'http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F85110490&auto_play=false&show_playcount=false&show_user=false&show_comments=false&amp;buying=false&liking=false&sharing=false&show_artwork=false&color=00e7ff';

function soundcloudId(src) {
   var p = /___________/;
   return (src.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}

soundcloudId(src);
```

And as a result, it would run the "src" through  the regex, and if a soundcloud link, would return 85110490. Otherwise, false.

Comment: Do you mean that the value returned should be 85110490? The 2F is part of the %2F escape sequence.

Comment: @Cfreak The only Soundcloud regex I found was:
var p = /^https?:\/\/(?:www.)?soundcloud.com\/[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[-_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*(?!\/sets(?:\/|$))(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[-_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*){1,2}\/?$/i;
But it doesn't work with embeds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/http:\/\/w.soundcloud\.com\/.*%2Ftracks%2F([0-9A-F]+)/
```

Runnable example: http://jsfiddle.net/mYf6P/

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, thank you! I'll update if I run into any issues.